# How do we add Checkboxes for an ownerdrawn list control in MFC?

Tags: checkbox, mfc, multi-select, clistctrl, ownerdrawn

How can I make an owner-draw list control with checkboxes. What I need is:
I have data separate, each has a different color code. I need to add this to a list control with the format :
This allows multiple selection
[checkbox] [color code rectangle] Text_Item
I need to use checkboxes to select which I want selected.
I Should be able to select multiple items from listcontrol without having to use CTRL+Click.

I have tried using DrawFrameControl For getting the checkboxes.But using which we are able to select only one item at a time.Following is my code I have used in my drawitem method.

void OwnerdrawListCtrl::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{

```
       bool sel = (lpDrawItemStruct->itemState && ODS_SELECTED);
       if
             DrawFrameControl(*pDC, rcItem, DFC_BUTTON, DFCS_CHECKED);
       else
             DrawFrameControl(*pDC, rcItem, DFC_BUTTON, DFCS_INACTIVE);
```

}

This is how I am adding the checkboxes  to my listCtrl.Im handling an NM_Click event in which Im setting the state of the i`enter code here`tem that is being clicked.

Comment: Set [`LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/extended-list-view-styles) style. Query checked state by calling [`CListCtrl::GetCheck()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=vs-2019#getcheck).

Comment: We cant add checkboxes for ownerdrawn controls using LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES

Comment: Try to use [custom draw](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra).

Comment: Use CListCtrlEx in place of CListCtrl